# Catch stderr in subprocess.check_call without using subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

I'd like to do the following:

- shell out to another executable from Python, using `subprocess.check_call`
- catch the stderr of the child process, if there is any
- add the stderr output to the CalledProcessError exception output from the parent process.

In theory this is simple. The `check_call` function signature contains a kwarg for `stderr`:

```
subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

However, immediately below that the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) contains the following warning:

> **Note**: Do not use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

The problem is that pretty much every example I can find for getting stderr from the child process mentions using `subprocess.PIPE` to capture that output.

How can you capture stderr from the child process without using `subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: Use subprocess.Popen instead.

Answer (score 3):

`stdout` and `stderr` can be assigned to almost anything that can receive data like a file-handle. you can even supply an open file_handle for writing to `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
file_handle = open('some_file', 'w')

subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=file_handle, stderr=file_handle, shell=False)
```

now every line of output goes to same file, or you could have a different file for each.

`stdin` also reads like a filehandle, using the `next()` to read each line as an input command to be sent on in addition to the initial `args`.

its a very robust function.

Comment: Is there a way to capture stdout/err into a variable so I can log it?