# Catch bash/git fatal in python

Tags: python, git, bash

I would like to write a simple python script which will be able to clone a git repository into desired directory. I used try...except construction to be able to catch all exceptions however it looks like I am not able to handle 'fatal' properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', 'git clone git@some_repo', '/tmp/some_directory'])
except Exception:
    print "There was a problem during repository configuration"
```

The output of the script above:

> fatal: repository 'git clone git@some_repo' does not exist
>
> There was a problem during repository configuration

To be more specific, I was rather expecting to get only the "There was a ..." message. Why do I get a 'fatal' message also?

Comment: That's standard error from the `git` call itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture `STDERR` of your `subprocess.check_call()` execution. See [Catch stderr in subprocess.check_call without using subprocess.PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089202/catch-stderr-in-subprocess-check-call-without-using-subprocess-pipe)

for details.

Comment: That example solves the problem with 'fatal', however is it possible to store the stdout into a variable?

Answer (score 3):

The message you are seeing is produced by the `git` command.

If you want to prevent that message from appearing you should redirect either standard error or all output to `/dev/null` through a shell, like:

```
subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', 'git clone git@some_repo', '/tmp/some_directory', '2&>/dev/null'], shell=True)
```

However, I'd recommend against that practice since you lose information on the actual cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

As previously specified you need to capture the standard error. Also, as the documentation specifies, `subprocess.check_call()` just raises an exception when the return code is non-zero.

So, you could mimic the behavior as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def clone_repository(): # customize your function parameters
    # prepare the arguments with your function parameters
    arguments = ['git', 'clone', 'git clone git@some_repo', '/tmp/some_directory']
    git_proc = subprocess.Popen(arguments)
    stdout, stderr = git_proc.communicate()
    if git_proc.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(arguments, git_proc.returncode)
    return stdout, stderr

try:
    stdout, stderr = clone_repository()
except (OSError, ValueError) as e:
    # this errors out when the arguments are invalid (ValueError)
    # or when there is an underlying file missing, etc (OSError)
    # put the print that you require for these errors
    pass 
except subprocess.CalledProcessError: 
    # you could use stderr to determine the underlying error
    print "There was a problem during repository configuration"
```